# Stepping by powers of two via DiscretePlot?

Tags: plotting

I have an equation that describes the time it takes a CPU to execute an operation as the number of cores increases. The number of cores increase as powers of two. $$0.64+\frac{12.8}{p}$$

```
 DiscretePlot[g[n], {n, 2, 2^12, 2^n}]
```

I understand that this is quite trivial as p grows large the function approaches 0.64 seconds, but I thought this would be a useful feature to know for the future. I don't need to discount the values between the powers. I just wanted to know if this was possible.

Comment: `DiscretePlot[g[2^n], {n, 2, 12}]`

Comment: That's smart, thank you Bob. I knew it was simple I just couldn't think of it.

Comment: Or, if you did not want to touch to `g[n]`, `DiscretePlot[g[n], {n, Table[2^i, {i, 12}]}]`.